# Make HTTP request with HttpURLConnection without fetching body

Tags: java

Is it possible to make a HTTP request with java.net.HttpURLConnection (or in some other way) and close the connection before the body of the response is fetched?

I use openConnection on a java.net.URL instance to create the HttpURLConnection and it seems like the body is already fetched, as soon as I've invoked openConnection.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve without fetching the body?

Comment: Why? If you just want the status line and headers, use a HEAD request.

Comment: Because I don't need the body. I can assure you, my reasons are legitimate. HEAD is not an option.